# Op amp with pmos

Tags: operational-amplifier, pmos

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQCNhn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is the gain (Vout/Vin) for the schematic?

Comment: I don't think that circuit works the way you think it does. It just stays off because Vin starts out larger than ground, so the op-amp saturates high which turns off the PMOS and it stays off since the PMOS being off keeps the voltage at the inverting input at ground (below Vin) which keeps the opamp output high which keeps the PMOS off, etc. In other words, Vout = 0V no matter what Vin is so the gain is zero.

Comment: Looks like a homework question. What do you think the gain would be? Tell us what you understand about this circuit.

Comment: I think with N-mos gain will be 2. With P-mos you have to make it inverting amp.

Comment: I am thinking the same way Toor told, but my friend is saying opamp behaves in the way it keeps the feedback network turned ON making the gain (1+(R2/R1))

Comment: No, that is only if the PMOS is replaced with an NMOS (and source-drain terminals flipped). Negative feedback requires at least one resistor to between MOSFET's source pin and the reference of the voltage being used to drive the gate . The resistors are in the right place for an NMOS, but not a PMOS. There is no negative feedback in this circuit.

Comment: I agree with @Toor's conclusion, but not the reasoning.  The FET and resistors form an inverting amplifier (just one that's referenced to +5V, not ground).  So to get overall negative feedback, the op-amp needs to be reversed.  Note that getting *stability* is a whole different problem, and not trivial.

Comment: You have no gain as it is drawn. You have either a latch or an oscillator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That circuit does not have a “gain” as it is positive feedback, and thus just a latch.

If you swap the opamp inputs, and ignore frequency response, the gain would be just 1+R2/R1 = 2. The transistor does not change this.

However, as opamps are designed to be just unity-gain stable maximizing their gain-bandwidth product, and the additional gain of the transistor is in its feedback loop and very likely >10, this configuration will be unstable and simply oscillate.

Answer (score 1):

Edgar Brown is correct, but let me expand.

For the moment, eliminate the FET. Then, as the op amp output rises Vout will rise also, right?

If you use an NMOS with the drain tied to Vcc, a rising op amp output will also cause Vout to rise.

If you use the PMOS, a rising op amp output will cause VOut to *decrease*, since Vgs will decrease and cause the current out to decrease. The PMOS stage inverts the gate voltage.

In order to fix this, you need to swap the + and - inputs. This will compensate for the inversion introduced by the PMOS FET.